# Difficulty Accessing Objective-C Class within Swift Framework in XCFramework

Tags: swift, objective-c, frameworks

I have a Swift Framework and I want to add an Objective C wrapper to access from Objective C project (This is the requirement for some reason).

I have wrapped up the Swift class to support in Objective as well.
I have created XCFramework and import it in the project.
Now I am encountering challenges in accessing an Objective-C class in Objective C, however I can access the Swift Classes.

Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code of Objective C class in Framework

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "FingerprintSDK/FingerprintSDK.h"

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface FingerprintSDKWrapper : NSObject
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance;
- (void)scanFingerprintWithKeywindow:(UIWindow *)window compeltion:(void (^)(NSArray<Images *> *resultArray))completion;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

Comment: Look's like you don't need mention `#import "FingerprintSDK/FingerprintSDK.h"` in  `FingerprintSDKWrapper`'s header.

Comment: Have you added `FingerprintSDKWrapper.h` to your framework's umbrella header?

Comment: Also...  > "This is the requirement for some reason" < If I were you, I would try to figure out what this reason is, because it shouldn't be necessary to do what you're doing.

Comment: @dalton_c I have tried adding 
#import <FingerprintScanSDK/FingerprintSDKWrapper.h> but I am getting an error "'FingerprintScanSDK/FingerprintSDKWrapper.h' file not found"

Comment: My client is working on NFI and they said Swift code is not supported at all. I don't know the reason. So I choose to provide them in both way.

Comment: Try just adding `#import "FingerprintSDKWrapper.h"`

Comment: #import "FingerprintSDKWrapper.h" same issue

Comment: @dalton_c Thanks for your support. I forgot to set class public in target membership

Answer (score 1):

A blunder wasted my time. Simple solution that works

1. Add Objective C class in Swift Framework
2. Set .h file as public in Target Membership
   [image]
3. import Objective C class in Umbrella header

   #import <yourSDK/ObjectiveC-class.h>

That's all you need.